# Combining find -execdir with grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I want to go through a bunch of files in various sub folders within a root directory quickly to get the video and audio format type.

I can get the information I need from a single file using:

```
ffprobe file.mp4 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "Stream"
```

I can run ffprobe for each file inside the root folder using

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -execdir ffprobe "{}" \;
```

What I am struggling with is to use grep with the second command to filter the output I want (as per the first command) and pipe the entire output into a file.
What is the missing link/s here?

Comment: What is the `>/dev/null` for may I ask?

Comment: Grep is not necessary there, ffprobe can extract that information on its own. Though we need to know the specifics of the output you expect to answer this.

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -execdir ffprobe "{}" \; 2>&1 | grep "Stream" > some_file.txt
```

The principle is the same really, it can be generalized as

```
some_command 2>&1 | grep "Stream"
```

where some_command in this case is

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -execdir ffprobe "{}" \;
```